# agreat vs. a great vs. greater

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, literature

Here is a quotation from the movie
Great Expectations Part 2 (1999; Director: Julian Jarrold)

> If the danger would be 50 times agreat
>   I should still have come to you.

The meaning is clearly "greater".
Should this be "agreat" or "a great"?
Is this correct usage?

> > Having read some comments below, I listen again to the audio. 
> >     Talking is very fast, words jumbled together.
> >     It could be he is just contracting "as great", and it is hard to tell if he says "had been" or "would be".
> >     And thanks for the "Project Gutenberg" reference.
> >     I will use it to correct some words I could not recognize from that movie.

Comment: Are you certain it's not "If the danger would be 50 times **as** great"?

Comment: "Agreat" is a rare word, probably archaic, apparently meaning "in gross" or "altogether".  I thus tend to favor @Juhasz 's suggestion that it's a typo for "as great".

Comment: The original Dickens text as provided by [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1400/1400-h/1400-h.htm) says *"If the danger had been fifty times as great, I should ha' come to see you, mind you, just the same."*

Comment: Wow! Did they change *had been* to *would be*?

Comment: Possibly the actor was "putting on" an accent and dropping the s in "as great."

Comment: Also, if I've got the right character in mind, he does not always speak in correct sentences. It's part of the characterization Dickens uses.